# How to replace all characters before and after specific place in text in Python

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a csv file with delimiter in text column. The number of delimiter in text column is different from row to row.

Example of csv data (delimiter is '_'):
ID_GROUP_TEXT_DATE_PART
101_group_1_Some text is here_23.06.2023_1
102_group_2_Some text is _ here_23.06.2023_1
103_group_3_Some text _ is _ here_23.06.2023_1
104_group_4_Some text is here_23.06.2023_1

I would like to correctly split the text by the columns.
The expected result is:

| ID | GROUP | TEXT | DATE | PART |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | group_1 | Some text is here | 23.06.2023 | 1 |
| 102 | group_2 | Some text is _ here | 23.06.2023 | 1 |
| 103 | group_3 | Some text _ is _ here | 23.06.2023 | 1 |
| 104 | group_4 | Some text is here | 23.06.2023 | 1 |

Comment: Did the answers resolve your question? If, so consider accepting the most suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a RegEx pattern in order to find the corresponding columns.

In your case you should create a pattern going like:
Number_group_n_text_date_Number

SO the final code should be:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

data = """
101_group_1_Some text is here_23.06.2023_1
102_group_2_Some text is _ here_23.06.2023_1
103_group_3_Some text _ is _ here_23.06.2023_1
104_group_4_Some text is here_23.06.2023_1
"""

pattern = r"(\d+)_group_(\d+)_(.+)_(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})_(\d)"

matches = re.findall(pattern, data)

df = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['ID', 'GROUP', 'TEXT', 'DATE', 'PART'])

print(df)
```